# RingCentral-Call-JS - 603 - Too many contacts

Tags: sip, ringcentral

I keep running into this error after setting up the webphone using [`ringcentral-call-js`](https://github.com/ringcentral/ringcentral-call-js).

The webphone will work for a few phone calls but eventually run into this. I have no idea what could be causing it and I don't find any information online about it.

```
SIP/2.0 603 Too Many Contacts
Via: SIP/2.0/WSS femcvfqh8p1f.invalid;branch=z9hG4bK6653901;received=24.108.116.162
To: <sip:1##########*101@sip.devtest.ringcentral.com>;tag=7BvYdcd7fcr
From: <sip:1##########*101@sip.devtest.ringcentral.com>;tag=vbdr8qojhl
Call-ID: 8frudde185qca0cgkkbrg1
CSeq: 3632 REGISTER
Content-Length: 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If instanceID is set, the connection will be reused and therefore the connection will not be re-established.

https://github.com/ringcentral/ringcentral-web-phone/blob/master/src/index.ts#L137